# Two Hudson Master on the same Windows Server

Tags: windows, deployment, service, hudson

I want to setup two Hudson Master on the same Hardware. This will make administering Hudson easier, since both servers are used by two different (and independent) teams.

So far I tried to install one server as a service. I verified the installation and it is running ok. I than copied the installation into another path and changed the service information (different service Name and description) and the httpPort. I then create the service, once using `sc.exe create` and once using `hudson.exe install`. In both cases the server startet. However, the configuration page acted goofy. So this approach is either not working at all or I missed another configuration file.

Does anyone has an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi Peter: have a look at my comment on this question to help you with your DNS alias problem when connecting to network shares on Win2003 - http://serverfault.com/questions/100871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same approach as documented in the question but avoided the copying of the original installation. So I created two folders and put a copy of hudson.war in it. Than I performed the following steps for both folders.

1. Start Hudson with `java -jar hudson.war`
2. Installed Hudson as a service using the web UI
3. went into the Hudson Base Dir and ran `hudson uninstall`
4. modified the port and the Service information in hudson.xml
5. installed the service through command line `hudson install`

Now I have two services and the first quick test looks promising.

UPDATE: Further test were successful. So I will use this approach going forward.